# Power BI - Anti Left join

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Data: 
I have two datasets, design-wise set up in Excel as a matrix with first ID and lots of rows, and with the rest of the columns in the data set have 1-1 headers id numbers, so like 500 rows and around 45 columns.
Like ID, ColumnB, ColumnC

The other matrix has the same headers, but different order. It does not seem to matter.

Challenge:
So I need to find the differences between the two. I made an anti-left join on ID and then I get the ID that are in the one data set and not the other, right? So I make one for each way, so I get the ID that are missing in the respective datasets(/matrix).
I need to do the same trick, even if both IDs are there and then I get only the data with a difference across all columns, so if there for a rowID is a "X" in ColumnB in dataset1, but NO "X" in ColumnB dataset2, then I want to include it in my new table. So if there are, for the two rows compared in the two datasets, a difference in just one of the columns, I need to know and want it in my new data, only the data with a difference.

Tried:
I tried to mark not only ID columns, but all the columns in the anti-left join setup, but it does not seem to work at all.